# How to get information from electrum wallet?

Tags: wallet, electrum, wallet-recovery, python, encryption

I have my wallet file and it is encrypted with a password.

How to decrypt wallet file using code?
Encryption seems similar to Fernet.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The electrum [FAQ](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-is-the-wallet-encrypted) answers "How is the wallet encrypted?" as follows:

> Electrum uses two separate levels of encryption:
>
> - Your seed and private keys are encrypted using AES-256-CBC. The private keys are decrypted only briefly, when you need to sign a transaction; for this you need to enter your password. This is done in order to minimize the amount of time during which sensitive information is unencrypted in your computer’s memory.
> - In addition, your wallet file may be encrypted on disk. Note that the wallet information will remain unencrypted in the memory of your computer for the duration of your session. If a wallet is encrypted, then its password will be required in order to open it. Note that the password will not be kept in memory; Electrum does not need it in order to save the wallet on disk, because it uses asymmetric encryption (ECIES).
>
> Wallet file encryption is activated by default since version 2.8. It is intended to protect your privacy, but also to prevent you from requesting bitcoins on a wallet that you do not control.

The above doesn't seem to me to be sufficient to decrypt the information but I expect inspecting some [Electrum source code](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum) would provide the missing dertails.

Searching for [decrypt electrum wallet file](https://www.google.com/search?q=decrypt+electrum+wallet+file) locates tools ind information that might be of some help.